Adding Multiple Owners and Allowing Original Owner to Remove Other Owners
I am trying to use the existing 2_Owner.sol in Remix Ethereum and make a few modifications.

Write up an addOwner() function that is public to everyone. This function takes one address as an argument and adds to the list of owners.

Write up a deleteOwner() function that is only accessible to the original owner who launches the contract. This function is used for removing one owner from the owner
list.


Can anyone please help by doing the above listed modifications/add-ons in the code below?
// SPDX-License-Identifier: GPL-3.0

pragma solidity >=0.7.0 <0.9.0;

import "hardhat/console.sol";

/**
 * @title Owner
 * @dev Set & change owner
 */
contract Owner {

    address private owner;

    // event for EVM logging
    event OwnerSet(address indexed oldOwner, address indexed newOwner);

    // modifier to check if caller is owner
    modifier isOwner() {
        // If the first argument of 'require' evaluates to 'false', execution terminates and all
        // changes to the state and to Ether balances are reverted.
        // This used to consume all gas in old EVM versions, but not anymore.
        // It is often a good idea to use 'require' to check if functions are called correctly.
        // As a second argument, you can also provide an explanation about what went wrong.
        require(msg.sender == owner, "Caller is not owner");
        _;
    }

    /**
     * @dev Set contract deployer as owner
     */
    constructor() {
        console.log("Owner contract deployed by:", msg.sender);
        owner = msg.sender; // 'msg.sender' is sender of current call, contract deployer for a constructor
        emit OwnerSet(address(0), owner);
    }

    /**
     * @dev Change owner
     * @param newOwner address of new owner
     */
    function changeOwner(address newOwner) public isOwner {
        emit OwnerSet(owner, newOwner);
        owner = newOwner;
    }

    /**
     * @dev Return owner address 
     * @return address of owner
     */
    function getOwner() external view returns (address) {
        return owner;
    }
} 


I've added the addOwner() and removeOwner() functions as per your given specifications in your existing code. Here's the revised code:
// SPDX-License-Identifier: GPL-3.0

pragma solidity >=0.7.0 <0.9.0;

/**
 * @title Owner
 * @dev Set & change owner
 */
contract Owner {

    address private owner;

    mapping(address => bool) public isAdditionalOwner;

    address[] public additionalOwners;

    // event for EVM logging
    event OwnerSet(address indexed oldOwner, address indexed newOwner);

    // modifier to check if caller is owner
    modifier isOwner() {
        // If the first argument of 'require' evaluates to 'false', execution terminates and all
        // changes to the state and to Ether balances are reverted.
        // This used to consume all gas in old EVM versions, but not anymore.
        // It is often a good idea to use 'require' to check if functions are called correctly.
        // As a second argument, you can also provide an explanation about what went wrong.
        require(msg.sender == owner, "Caller is not owner");
        _;
    }

    /**
     * @dev Set contract deployer as owner
     */
    constructor() {
        owner = msg.sender; // 'msg.sender' is sender of current call, contract deployer for a constructor
        emit OwnerSet(address(0), owner);
    }

    /// @notice Called by anyone to add the additional owner.
    /// @param addr       Address to be added as additional owner
    function addOwner(address addr) public {  
        require(
            !isAdditionalOwner[addr],
            "address is already an additional owner"
        );
        isAdditionalOwner[addr] = true;
        additionalOwners.push(addr);
    }

    /// @notice Called by original owner to remove the passed address from the list of additional owners.
    /// @param addr                     Address to be removed from the list of additional owners
    function removeOwner(
        address addr
    ) external isOwner {
        require(
            isAdditionalOwner[addr],
            "no such additional owner exists"
        );
        
        uint256 index = getIndexOfAdditionalOwner(addr);
  
        isAdditionalOwner[addr] = false;

        address temp = additionalOwners[index];

        additionalOwners[index] = additionalOwners[additionalOwners.length - 1];

        additionalOwners[additionalOwners.length - 1] = temp;

        additionalOwners.pop();

    }

    function getIndexOfAdditionalOwner(
        address addr
    ) internal view returns (uint256 i) {
        
        for (i = 0; i < additionalOwners.length; i++) {
            if (additionalOwners[i] == addr) {
                return i;
            }
        }
    }

    /**
     * @dev Change owner
     * @param newOwner address of new owner
     */
    function changeOwner(address newOwner) public isOwner {
        emit OwnerSet(owner, newOwner);
        owner = newOwner;
    }

    /**
     * @dev Return owner address 
     * @return address of owner
     */
    function getOwner() external view returns (address) {
        return owner;
    }
} 

